# Lambda with SQSEvent & large batch size invokes multiple instances each handling few items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, amazon-sqs

Bit of background,
I'm using Serverless and .Net to create a lambda with a SQS trigger.
The event trigger is set with batch size of 10k and wait time (Batch Window ie `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds`) of 30 seconds.
Queue's visibility timeout is set to almost 16 minutes.

Now that I've set the lambda to reserved concurrency of only 1 and ran a test where I send 100 items to the queue & was hoping to see only one lambda invocation with exactly those 100 items.

Problem was that it separated the items in the queue and invoked the lambda five times instead, causing five packages to be created as part of the lambda's functionality instead of the one package I wanted. (FYI the lambda's output creates packages in s3 of the messages. I want to have fewer packages that are large.)

**Now the question**: Is this the expected behavior? and if so why is it so when I've set the queue to accumulate up to 10k items and instead it settled for 15.

According to the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource) the lambda can grab fewer messages than the batchSize if the payload is larger than 256kb but my messages are very small and 100 messages are no where near 256kb. So that can't be the cause.

Suggestions for alternatives to dealing with this issue are also welcome, right now I'm thinking of running an event bridge scheduler that calls lambda with SQS ReceiveMessage api and creates a single package but then I also have to make sure to properly delete the queue afterwards.

I'm a bit clueless here, I'd appreciate any ideas you guys have. Thanks.

Comment: What's the sqs trigger batch size?

Comment: It says in the question: 10k

Comment: any news about this? I'm in the same scenario

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Problem was that it separated the items in the queue and invoked the lambda **five times** instead, causing five packages to be created as part of the lambda's functionality instead of the one package I wanted.

I think that this is probably because there are **five SQS pooling threads** that lambda uses to pool SQS. From [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/):

> Lambda service will begin polling the SQS queue using **five parallel long-polling connections**.

So even though you had reserved concurrency of 1, lambda still uses the 5 threads (you can't control that), and your **SQS messages were distributed** into these threads. Then, each thread invoked your lambda function, one by one, resulting in observed 5 invocations.

Comment: So @Marcin you're saying, that whatever the batchIndex is set to it will grab that number divided by 5? And it will ignore MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds? Sounds like a AWS bug. No?

Comment: @Rafi The exact details how this works is not documented, at least I don't know where. But you always have these five threads pulling. So your experiment agrees with the use of the threads. Maybe you can try do some other tests to further evaluate the pooling behavior, keeping in mind these 5 threads.

Comment: @Marcin - Definition of concurrency in the context of lambda is : ["Concurrency is the number of in-flight requests your AWS Lambda function is handling at the same time"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html#understanding-concurrency). So reserved concurrency should apply to requests and not to the number of lambda instances created. Views?

Answer (score 0):

I think a FIFO queue could be your solution:

"FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queues are designed to enhance messaging between applications when the order of operations and events is critical, or **where duplicates can't be tolerated**."

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` value on your event source mapping. That allows you to collect up to 5 minutes of messages before invoking the lambda.

Keep in mind that SQS is a queuing mechanism, not a batching mechanism. The batching that is part of the event source mapping, or that is generally available with SQS, is intended to reduce the number of calls. It is not designed to provide guaranteed batch sizes. While setting the above value may achieve your current goal I don't know that you can reasonably expect it to always work that way. Also keep in mind that SQS is an "at least once" delivery mechanism (unless you use FIFO, which has a batch limit of 10).

Comment: we tried that as it says in the the question we set it to 30.